# Error when installing factoextra on R - cannot remove previous installation of rlang

Tags: r, github, installation, package, rlang

I'm trying to install factoextra. I'm running R v.4.0.3.
I have used

```
    > install.packages("devtools")
    > library("devtools")
    > install_github("kassambara/factoextra")
```

It then asks if I wish to update the packages:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 4.0 from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Downloading GitHub repo kassambara/factoextra@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                          
2: CRAN packages only           
3: None                         
4: rlang (0.4.8 -> 0.4.9) [CRAN]
```

So I selected 1, to update all packages and it returns with:

```
    package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: Failed to install 'factoextra' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
```

I have very little experience with R and I really don't know what to do. I need factoextra so I can run an fviz_pca command.

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get this error if rlang is already loaded. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815140/r-package-updates) previous post.

Comment: Should I just delete rlang from my library then?

Comment: Just start a new R session. factoextra is also on CRAN, so you should be able to get it with install.packages("factoextra")

Comment: Thank you so much! Maybe this seemed like a stupid question to you but install.packages("factoextra") solved it!